# Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java

I'm trying to sort a list. I used `Collections.sort(list)`, and I got an IllegalArgumentException Exception.
I know this works on jdk6 and jdk7 is using TimSort. The rules I got is below. I think I got it right, but it doesn't work.

Is there anyone can give me a situation where my code doesn't work? Thanks a lot

RULES:

```
> 1.sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))
> 
> 2.((compare(x, y)>0) && (compare(y, z)>0)) implies compare(x, z)>0
> 
> 3.compare(x, y)==0 implies that sgn(compare(x, z))==sgn(compare(y, z)) for all z





//StringUtil.isBlank(str) return if str==null||str.trim().length()==0
@Override
public int compareTo(NovelChapter o) {
    if(o == null){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(o.equals(this) || this == o){
        return 0;
    }

    if(!StringUtil.isBlank(o.getSourceUrl())&& !StringUtil.isBlank(this.getSourceUrl())){
        if(o.getSourceUrl().length() != this.getSourceUrl().length()){
            return o.getSourceUrl().compareTo(this.getSourceUrl());
        }
        else{
            return o.getSourceUrl().compareTo(this.getSourceUrl()) * (-1);
        }
    }
    else if(!StringUtil.isBlank(o.getSourceUrl())&& !StringUtil.isBlank(this.getSourceUrl())){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(!StringUtil.isBlank(o.getSourceUrl())&& StringUtil.isBlank(this.getSourceUrl())){
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

BTW, `System.setProperty("java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort", "true");` is using jdk6, it does not solve the problem itself.

================================================

thanks for all the answers,and I changed the code,now it throw NPE .Is it better now ?But it still give me the same Exception.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(NovelChapter o) {

    if(o == null){
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }else if(o.equals(this) || this == o){
        return 0;
    }

    String self = this.getSourceUrl();
    String item = o.getSourceUrl();

    if(self == null && item != null){
        return -1;
    }else if (self == null && item != null){
        return 1;
    }else if(self == null && item == null){
        return 0;
    }

    if(self.length() == item.length()){
        return self.compareTo(item);
    }else{
        return self.compareTo(item) * (-1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you give a minimal example for which you get this exception?

Comment: try removing `if(o == null)`, it does not look to me handling `null`s can ever satisfy the first rule (`sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))`) since you cannot call `null.compareTo(obj)`

Comment: the list is too long and I failed to add it to comment.....they are URLs such as www.bxwx.org/b/3/3575/609844.html
www.bxwx.org/b/3/3575/609841.html
www.bxwx.org/b/3/3575/609843.html
www.bxwx.org/b/3/3575/609842.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see the specific cause of that exception, but there are a couple of problems in the code you have shown us.

1. The `compareTo` method should not be used on `null`, so your special handling of `null` should not be there.  The comparator >>should<< throw an NPE.  (And the corollary is that you should not be attempting to sort arrays / collections that contain `null` values.)
2. Your use of `trim` looks inconsistent.  You trim when you look for "blank" URLs, but not when comparing "non-blank" URLs.  Weird.

I would add that your code is verbose and inefficient.  Rather than repeatedly calling that `isBlank` utility in a chain of if / else statements you should simply convert the two URLs into strings (I'm guessing) that can be compared directly.

Finally, the fact that you have to have an `isBlank` method at all says (to me) that the rest of your code is doing a poor job of maintaining data consistency.  There should be exactly one representation that means "no source URL" ... not (at least) three.

---

There are a number of possible causes of this problem that can only be eliminated by examining the complete classes involved ... starting with `NovelChapter` and whatever it is that `getSourceUrl()` returns.

Comment: thanks for your advises.I changed the code according to your advise,is it better now?But I still got the Exception.

Comment: There are a number of possible causes of this problem that can only be eliminated by examining the complete classes involved ... starting with NovelChapter and whatever it is that getSourceUrl() returns.

Answer (score 0):

From `Comparable` Javadoc:

> Note that null is not an instance of any class, and e.compareTo(null)
>   should throw a NullPointerException even though e.equals(null) returns
>   false.

Comment: This is a rule that I didn't know.And I handle the situation where e.compareTo(null),but still the same Exception....T.T